# Th tag display flex gives weird output

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I'm making a React app and I want to add an icon to the `th` tag. So far I have:

```html
<th><p>col name</p><ArrowDown /></th>
```

I want text and icon to be vertically centered, so I apply flexbox to `th`:

```css
th {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

And that's what I see:
[image]

Anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`th` elements inherently have a display value of `display: table-cell`, so changing them to `display: flex` will have dramatic consequences, as you've seen.

### 1. Try 'inline-flex' instead of 'flex'

Like `display: block`, `display: flex` elements won't naturally lie next to each other.

Like `display: inline-block`, however, `display: inline-flex` elements will.

This probably won't be 100% right either, as table cells (including headers) behave differently from inline elements.

### 2. (Preferred) Use another element inside the `th`

```html
<th>
  <div class="header-inner">
    <p>col name</p>
    <ArrowDown />
  </div>
</th>
```

```css
.header-inner {
  display: flex;
}
```

While this adds another element to the DOM, it's probably the safer approach. You aren't disrupting the inherent layout properties of the `<th>` elements, and you get the expected flexbox behavior you're after.

In general, if you're trying to achieve a complicated layout with minimal elements, and it's not behaving as you'd like, try separating your CSS concerns. Let the table headers have their naturally opinionated layout properties, and add your complications to a separate element.

Answer (score 1):

I try this

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th><span>A</span><span>B</span></th>
    <th><span>A</span><span>B</span></th>
  </tr>
</table>

table {
 width: 500px;
}
th {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

And it works